# Configure Spring 4 JDBC JDBCTemplate with Connection Provider class

Tags: java, spring, connection-pooling, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Is there a way i can configure the spring 4 JDBCTemplate data source with a Connection provider class like the one hibernate provides?

I have connections managed by connection pool provided by a Java class. I can get connection through the provider class but i'm not sure how to configure the JDBCTemplate datasource with that.

```
@Configuration
public class MyDataSourceConfig {
/**
 * My data source.
 * 
 * @return the data source
 */
@Bean(name = "myDS")
@Primary
public DataSource myDataSource() {
    // I need to add a way to get a data source object using the connection
    // from the class
    Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
    /**
     * TODO Add code to create data source with the connection provider
     * DBConnection.class
     */
    return dataSource;

}

@Bean(name = "jdbcMydb")
@Autowired
public JdbcTemplate hrdbJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("myDS") DataSource jdbcMydb) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(jdbcMydb);
}}
```

Comment: Question is unclear. Please try to include more information. Start by including some code and explaining at what step you are facing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be for you to extend [AbstractDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/AbstractDataSource.html) and override getConnection() method and write new DataSource for you. Or to probably make easier by extending concrete classes like [SimpleDriverDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/SimpleDriverDataSource.html)

Comment: Thanks @kuhajeyan!  It worked. I extended the AbstractDataSource on DBConnection class and modified the dataSource bean to return a new instance of DBConnection.